# Is there a way to dynamically set CDK Stage env account?

Tags: aws-cdk

Is there a way to dynamically set [Stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.Stage.html) account ?

I would like to simplify multi stages pipeline creation by leveraging cdk [pipelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/pipelines-readme.html) construct but I would like to dynamically determine the stages accounts id:

```
let enhancedProps = {
    ...props
  };

  const accountId = ssm.StringParameter.fromStringParameterAttributes(this, `${id}-account-id`, {
    parameterName: '/accounts/staging/id',
    // 'version' can be specified but is optional.
  }).stringValue;

  enhancedProps.env = {account: accountId};

  pipeline.addApplicationStage(new LambdaSQSLambdaStage(this, 'staging', enhancedProps));
```

But I end up with an error :

```
You cannot add a dependency from 'SqsXRayStack/staging/LambdaSQSLambdaStack' (in Stage 'SqsXRayStack/staging') to 'SqsXRayStack' (in the App): dependency cannot cross stage boundaries
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to get the advantage of using `cdk.json` config file.

*cdk.json*

```json
{
    "context": {
        "accounts": {
            "dev": "id1",
            "staging": "id2",
            "production": "id3"
        }
    }
}
```

then in *Stack.ts*

```js
const accountId = scope.node.tryGetContext('accounts')[stage]
```

The `stage` will be passed from aws-cdk entry-point.ts

Comment: Yep but that's means pushing those accountIds to the git repo to be shared to all devs which seems to be not recommended ... I found a way by using "aws-sdk" calling "Organizations.ListAccounts" API in the TS code itself but the code is a bit too complex for what I want to achieve ...

Comment: You may also load/store the list of account ids in ssm/parameters store.

Comment: That's what I tried in my example but this create cross stage dependency which is not supported ... Or I missed something ?

Comment: Could you try to load parameter with StringParameter.fromStringParameterName() ?